# log-log scale y axis ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(runif(100,0,0.02), 1:100)
colnames(df1) <- c("a","b")

df2 <- data.frame(runif(100,0,0.3), 1:100)
colnames(df2) <- c("a","b")
```

I need two scatterplots (one for each dataframe) side by side, with a log-log scale on y axis that looks exactly like this (external yticks, minor y ticks between all the labels and so) but limited to 1 (not 10):

[image]

I tried (scatterplot of 1 dataframe):

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(b), y=a)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                     labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks()
```

but I still don't get what I want

Comment: What code did you try ?

Answer (score 1):

adding `limits=c(10^-4,1)` and changing `labels=comma` did the work!

Final code:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(b), y=a)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                     breaks = comma,
                     labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)),
                     limits=c(10^-4,1)) +
  annotation_logticks()
```

besides, hints how to display only significative figures (ie 1 instead of 1.0000, or 0.1 instead of 0.1000) in the `comma` function? thanks

Comment: solved. for getting read of trailing 0: Instead of `labels = comma` use `labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE, drop0trailing = T)`